# Space in search box not working

Tags: magento

I searched all over net and couldnt found answer for my problem. In online store www.toner123.si (magento platforma) I have "search box". I use FREE product Catalog_Search_Refinement 1.0.7. Every time I enter online store and go to search box, I **can not use "space bar".** Can`t write any word with empty space. **After I do one search cycle it works ok**. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to your **js/magentothem/ma.style1.js** file.

On around line 178, you have the following code:

```
if(settings.allowKeyboardCtrl){
    $bn1(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.which==39){
            nextSlide = ActSlide-1;
            stopAutoplay();
            jumpTo(nextSlide);
        }else if(e.which==37){
            prevSlide = ActSlide+1;
            stopAutoplay();
            jumpTo(prevSlide);
        }else if(e.which==32){
            if(intval){stopAutoplay();}
            else{autoplay();}
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is with `return false;`.  Since you are binding the `keydown` event to the `document`, returning false for `e.which==32` (which is the spacebar) will prevent the spacebar from working completely.  Simply remove `return false;` from this if case and it will work again, like this:

```
if(settings.allowKeyboardCtrl){
    $bn1(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.which==39){
            nextSlide = ActSlide-1;
            stopAutoplay();
            jumpTo(nextSlide);
        }else if(e.which==37){
            prevSlide = ActSlide+1;
            stopAutoplay();
            jumpTo(prevSlide);
        }else if(e.which==32){
            if(intval){stopAutoplay();}
            else{autoplay();}
        }
    });
```